# How do you call methods from an Apache Axis web service in a Spring MVC application?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, axis

I have an Apache Axis web service that handles file uploads and enters and retrieves information from an Oracle database. It has all the functions my Spring MVC app needs. What I want to know is, how would I go about calling the methods from the web service in my application and giving them the parameters they need to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [wsdl2java](http://axis.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html#UsingWSDLWithAxis) to build your client stubs which are Java classes that you call.

Comment: Seems to be what I needed. Thanks.